# Ссылка для добавления товара в магазин woocommerce через Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

Магазин на Wordpress, плагин Woocommerce.

Прошлый разработчик создал форму для добавления товара на странице категорий, она делает редирект на `http://domen.ru/product-category/cart/?add-to-cart=id` через POST передается количество товара.

Нужно переделать, чтобы товар добавлялся через AJAX.

Я написал скрипт для отслеживания события отправки формы, в поле url указываю url из action формы, товар добавляется, но ответом приходит код страницы. Нужно указать какой-то url, чтобы ответ приходил json допустим. Чтобы его можно было обработать в скрипте.

Подскажите, какой url указать?

Comment: WooCommerce по умолчанию включает режим добавления в корзину через ajax. Кнопка "В корзину" должна иметь класс `ajax_add_to_cart`. Обработка находится в файле `wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/frontend/add-to-cart.js` Ищите, что сломал ваш предыдущий разработчик.

Comment: В итоге так и сделали. Заменили форму, на код кнопки из темы по умолчанию и все заработало, а количество добавили костыльным скриптом. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно реализовать данный функционал в штатных шаблонах вывода товаров Woocommerce, то там это уже реализовано (ищите баг).

Если же в своем шаблоне, где товара (товары) извлекаются примерно так:

```
$product_custom = wc_get_product( product_id );
```

То тогда в шаблоне ссылки должны быть обязательно классы `ajax_add_to_cart add_to_cart_button` и атрибут `data-product_id = product_id`

Ссылку в теге `<a href='.$product_custom->add_to_cart_url().'` можно тоже оставить на тот случай если в настройках Woocommerce выключить поддержку AJAX для кнопки добавления в корзину.